# Rails + Read json from remote site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I was wondering if it is possible with rails to read in the json content of an external Joomla website?

Would I need to use Nokogiri to complete such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Nokogiri is for parsing html. This is how you would do it plain ruby (in rails you probably don't even need to require those):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

response = open("http://path.to.website/file.json").read
JSON.parse(response)
```